# Contact Form on Windows Azure

Tags: plugin-contactform

I’m having some trouble getting a contact form to submit and function correctly. The live instance of the site is on Windows Azure but my staging and local versions are unix. Is there any reason for Pixel & Tonic's Contact Form plugin not to function because of the platform? Perhaps it's a lower level issue with PHP setup or my Craft configuration on Windows.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The short answer is "no", but it might be easier to help figure out what's going on if you edit the original question and include the behaviors you're seeing.  Are you getting error messages? Are the emails not being sent?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no reason why Contact Form would fail on Windows Azure specifically.

If I had to guess, I bet you've got your email settings "Protocol" configured to use `PHP Mail`. That particular method of handling email is notoriously unreliable, which would explain why it's working on some of your servers but not others.

I'd highly recommend switching to an `SMTP` service. I've personally had a very good experience with [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/), and I've heard others rave about [SparkPost](https://www.sparkpost.com/). Regardless of which service you choose, SMTP is far superior to PHP mail.

I'd also suggest reading the full Craft article on [Troubleshooting Email Errors...](https://craftcms.com/support/troubleshooting-email-errors)